# ## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When I knit my R Markdown document to pdf, some of my pages have this Error
`## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,` : See screenshot below. What could be the problem? I am not using any new fonts and the laptop is a mac.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set `pdf.options(encoding = )` in a previous code chunk (or in the first code chunk in your document). Since you didn't provide a reproducible example, there is no way for us to tell which encoding is appropriate in your case. [See this article for more info](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/graphics/#encoding-of-multibyte-characters).

Comment: In the column, there were specific characters that threw this error. I changed it and now its working okay

Answer (score 1):

You are using an [en-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash); for some reason there are specific bugs for this character. See

```
 R -e 'library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Big–booté")'
open Rplots.pdf
```

[image: Té, té, té!!!]

As you can see, the “é” characters are processed correctly but the en-dashes get turned into dots. Presumably, some R code is attempting to kludge things up by folding the characters back into some obsolete, platform-specific character set; and failing on special characters such as the en-dash.

[Switching the `png` or `cairo_pdf` output driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64471402/435004) fixes the problem (at least on Mac OS X and the latest R version 4.0.3):

```
R -e 'png(filename = "win.png"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Big–boo–té"); dev.off()'
open win.png
```

[image: Thanks, John Whorfin.]

Or as far as Rmarkdown is concerned,

```
R -e 'rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", "pdf_document", output_file="foo.pdf", runtime = "static", output_options = list(dev = "cairo_pdf"))'
```